# MySQL page visitors statistics, database overflow protection

Tags: php, mysql, statistics, ip, overflow

I'm writing page visitors statistics. For each "visit", I'm saving the:

- the md5 ip of the user (privacy policy...)
- id of a page visited (for example 11, this is the id of a page called gallery)
- datetime of visit
- query (for example galery=cars&image=18)

I don't care that many users can have the same ip, as recognizing each user is still impossible, this is sufficient for me.

---

After implementing this, I thought about a possible problem. Someone can proxy his ip, and random the page query. I know, that sound a little bit confusing and scary, but this is possible. In that case, for every such a request I'm inserting one row to a database (of a size, let's say for example 128bits).

So if someone is really malignant, he can loop his requests, and after a few days, I will have my database full.

The question is: **How to resist such a possible attack?**
I know that this scenario is a dark one, but I remember our school informatics challenges. And I know that this scenario is dark, but possible. Human imagination is uncharted.

---

I'm not sure what code should I present here, as my problem is as always theoretical one. Maybe a little sketch of my script. It is much more complicated, but the problem can be reduced to such a lines:

```
<?php
    $visit = array(
        'ip' => = md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), // privacy policy
        'pageid' => '...', // page id number
        'query' => '...' // query part of url from address bar for example a=1&c=10
    );
    if (inDatabase('visits', $visit)) {
        echo 'Page visited';
    }
    else {
        $visit['date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        insertToDatabase('visits', $visit); // if random IP, and random query, it inserts for every request!!!
    }
?>
```

Comment: is there a possibility something like that gonna happen? Did something like that happen before? You cant prevent that, but even if the log would be inserting 1MB/s it would take 12 days to fill 1TB disk. DDOS would be much easier and faster. Just add some more storage space, and add some task to check size of log DB. Make it to send you a warning message if the size gets too large so you can make backup and clean the table - or make it automatically

Comment: After a while of reading, and your comment, I think that You are right... I'm too squeamish about it. I think you can make an answer from that, and I will accept it, as these are the same conclusions that I came with. Thx for your interest and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a possibility something like that gonna happen? Did something like that happen before? You cant prevent that, but even if the log would be inserting 1MB/s it would take 12 days to fill 1TB disk. DDOS would be much easier and faster. Just add some more storage space, and add some task to check size of log DB. Make it to send you a warning message if the size gets too large so you can make backup and clean the table - or make it automatically